# Asp.net session fixation (ASP.NET_sessionid)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Asp.net_SessionId is generated default by the system. Whenever this value copied from one browser to another user automatically access the pages inside login credentials.

case: First I logged in with my credentials in one browser (chrome). Now I open same browser in private mode (again chrome). Now I'll copy logged in browser session value to private mode and try to access the pages like dashboard, profile, settings etc. So here just by copying the session value I am able to access all the pages that require login.

How to prevent this? Please give me some suggestions.

I am able to prevent this in cross browser but I am not able to prevent it in same browser.

**What I have tried:**

I implemented the technique described here, but it's not working in my case. Yes its working with two different browser but not with single browser.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859579/Hack-proof-your-asp-net-applications-from-Session

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What possible use would you have for preventing someone from opening another Chrome window in private mode and copying a session ID over?

Comment: How is this different from a user opening two tabs in the same browser (not in private mode)? Do you want to prevent that too?

Comment: It's too different from opening new tab and new window. In new tab application will use same cookies while in another window new cookies will be generated. Both are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever this value copied from one browser to another user
>   automatically access the pages inside login credentials.

It depends on how you authenticate the user. If you just use Session State to keep track of user authentication like classic ASP days, it is true.

Nowadays, we use ASP.Net Identity or Form Authentication *(Membership Provider)* via SSL in which tokens are encrypted, and sign-out everywhere features. So it is not easily to hack Authentication Cookie in SSL (I do not say that impossible).

In ASP.Net MVC, we do not need to use Session State like we used to in ASP.Net Web Form and Classic ASP. Besides, using Session State directly becomes a bad practice in ASP.Net MVC.

The bottom line is if you use ASP.Net Identity or Form Authentication via SSL, I won't even worry about it. If you haven't use those, you definitely want to consider using it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, can you please provide a brief idea/code either about ASP.Net Identity or Form Authentication via SSL.

Comment: As you suggested, I implemented ASP.Net Identity but no luck. It creates .ASPXAUTH cookie with encrypted value but when I copy this value from one browser to another then it's allowing user to access the site without login.

Comment: The concept of cookie based authentication is it if someone has valid cookie the can access your site anywhere *even from console application*. All major websites including banks work that way. There is no risk you should be concern as long as you send the cookie via SSL.

Comment: That's true sir, but using "Burp suit" anyone can login into the site by changing cookie value, then what'll be meaning of login. I need a concrete solution for login where no one can login without valid username and password. Please suggest me a way...

Comment: Encrypted cookie is the end result after entering ***valid*** username and password. No one can steal that cookie from you *(if you use SSL)*, unless your computer is compromised. If your computer is compromised, hacker won't even bother stealing that cookie; instead, they will install ***key logger*** in your computer.

Comment: This'll also will not work, what's the meaning here from encrypting cookie, while it'll be steal by someone. I want for every sucessfull logged in user have a cookie that can't be used on other machine, even if someone copy that cookie and use it in other machine.

Comment: `*what's the meaning here from encrypting cookie*` Using ***https*** is enough; you do not need to encrypt a cookie *(It is just another layer of protection)*.  `*I want for every sucessfull logged in user have a cookie that can't be used on other machine, even if someone copy that cookie and use it in other machine.*` Currently, no such technology exists yet. If you have some times, you might want to read the source code of [ASP.Net Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity).